# Check all is not adding all the sum to the total input

Tags: jquery

I have some inputs with values and a total at the end of he form.

If I check one input, it's working, the value is added to the total.

If I check all, it checks all the check boxes but the total is not working. From what I noticed, it tries it calculates the sum of all checked check boxes before to check all the check boxes.

Many thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.fn.myFunction = function(){
    sum = 0;
    $('#formular :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($('#valoare_'+parseInt($(this).attr("id"))).val());
    });

    $('#total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  }

  $('#formular :checkbox').click(function() {
      $.fn.myFunction();
  });

  $("#checkAll").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    $.fn.myFunction();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formular">
<input id="checkAll" type="checkbox"><label for="checkAll"><b>Select all</b></label><br/>
<input id='1_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_1" name="valoare_1" type="number" value="31.20"><br/>
<input id='2_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_2" name="valoare_2" type="number" value="41.20"><br/>
<input id='3_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_3" name="valoare_3" type="number" value="51.20"><br/>
<input id="total" name="total" type="number" value="0.00">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#checkAll` is included in the calculation for sum which should not. Just moved above the form(for testing).

Also, you can add below for any input change so it will update the sum.

```
$('#formular input').change(function() {
          $.fn.myFunction();
      });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.fn.myFunction = function(){
    sum = 0;
    $('#formular :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($('#valoare_'+parseInt($(this).attr("id"))).val());
    });

    $('#total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  }

  $('#formular :checkbox').click(function() {
      $.fn.myFunction();
  });
 $('#formular input').change(function() {
      $.fn.myFunction();
  });
  $("#checkAll").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    $.fn.myFunction();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkAll" type="checkbox"><label for="checkAll"><b>Select all</b></label><br/>
<form id="formular">

<input id='1_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_1" name="valoare_1" type="number" value="31.20"><br/>
<input id='2_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_2" name="valoare_2" type="number" value="41.20"><br/>
<input id='3_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_3" name="valoare_3" type="number" value="51.20"><br/>
<input id="total" name="total" type="number" value="0.00">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is broken, because you don't have int value in checkAll checkbox Id. Just add small condition:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.fn.myFunction = function(){
    sum = 0;
    $('#formular :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        const id = parseInt($(this).attr("id"))
        if (id) {
          sum += parseFloat($('#valoare_'+id).val());
        }
    });

    $('#total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  }

  $('#formular :checkbox').click(function() {
      $.fn.myFunction();
  });

  $("#checkAll").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    $.fn.myFunction();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this version where I cache the checkboxes

```js
$(function() {
  const $check = $('#formular :checkbox[id$=_check]');
  $.fn.myFunction = function() {
    sum = 0;
    $check.each(function() {
      sum += this.checked ? parseFloat($(this).next().val()) : 0;
    });
    $('#total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  }

  $("#checkAll").on("click", function() {
    $check.prop("checked", this.checked);
    $.fn.myFunction();
  });
  $check.on("click", function() {
    if (!this.checked) $("#checkAll").prop("checked", false)
    $.fn.myFunction()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formular">
  <input id="checkAll" type="checkbox"><label for="checkAll"><b>Select all</b></label><br/>
  <input id='1_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_1" name="valoare_1" type="number" value="31.20"><br/>
  <input id='2_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_2" name="valoare_2" type="number" value="41.20"><br/>
  <input id='3_check' type="checkbox"><input id="valoare_3" name="valoare_3" type="number" value="51.20"><br/>
  <input id="total" name="total" type="number" value="0.00">
</form>
```